# Getting KeyError: '61' while iterating through rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to drop rows which has int values in patient column of the dataframe.

Here is my code:

```
for i in df['patient']:
    if i.isdigit() == True:
        df.drop(df.loc[df['patient'][i]])
df
```

But I am getting `KeyError: '61'`

How to get it right?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
m=df['patient'].str.isdigit().fillna(False)
#OR(use anyone since both are doing the same thing)
m=df['patient'].str.isnumeric().fillna(False)
#Finally:
df=df[~m]
#OR
df.loc[~m]
```

OR

```
m=df['patient'].str.isalpha().fillna(False)
#Finally:
df=df[m]
#OR
df=df.loc[m]
```

Comment: I tried, its giving me an error.  ```ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values```

Comment: @user16309118 this was because the dataset contains `NaN's` so do you  want to include the `NaN's` in your result or drop them

Comment: I want to drop them. I already used dropna

Comment: @user16309118 updated answer....kindly have a look ***:)***